# Boost linker error

Tags: boost, linker-errors

I'm new to boost lib and trying to compile a simple example about how the serialization works with boost library from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp

on compiling i get the linker error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc80-mt-sgd-1_42.lib'
```

I also tried to copy and put the .lib file in project directory but the VS 8.0 complier can't still link to it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library

Comment: I had to change it to (/MDd) in complier linking options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post-answer the question fully..

The error is from the auto-linking Boost implements and it's telling you that it picked to auto-link a version of the serialization lib that you don't have compiled. You could try compiling the different version by following the instructions in building from source (see [building from source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source)). Specifically the "mt-sgd" tag on the library name tells you that it's looking for the multi-threaded static debug C++ runtime with the debug version of the library (see [library naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)). Switching to "/MDd", as you did, makes the compiler switch to the multi-threaded dynamic debug C++ runtime (see [MSVC run-time flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28VS.71%29.aspx)) which happens to be the default build for Boost. And hence it then finds it, as you already have it built.